# Python Scoring System Referenced Before Assignment

Tags: python

I have tried to make my scoring system for my quiz work for days now with no avail. I have tried 'global', +=, score = score + 1, and so on and I am always getting pretty much the same error. "Local Variable "score" referenced before assignment", however I have put 'score = 0' at the top, also noting that the question is in a 'def' function. I tried some tests in a separate document and when I remove the function from the code, it seemed to add / subtract points fine. I would like to have functions within my code to be able to return to the beginning of the question when a incorrect answer is inputted. Thanks.

Whole Code:
https://repl.it/@oliverpurchase/test2

```
import time
score = 0

def question1():

  question_1 = input("1.\n2.\n3.\n4.\n")

  if question_1 == "3":
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Correct!")
    score += 1
    print ("Your now have a score of ",s,"!")

  else:
    print("Incorrect..")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    score -= 1
    print ("Your now have a score of ",s,"!")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    print("Try Again")
    time.sleep(0.5)
    return question1()
question1()
```

Comment: Declare `global score` in your function.

Comment: I have about 15 questions in the quiz, do I have to add a global in all of them?

Comment: If you want to update a global variable in them all, yes.

Comment: Thank you so much. Trying to figure out how where to put global tags for days.